# Linq in selecting item from ListViewItemCollections in c#

Tags: c#, linq

how to select a ListViewItem from ListViewItemCollections using Linq in C#?

i tried on using this but it didn't work..

```
ListViewItemCollections lv = listview1.items;

var test = from xxx in lv where xxx.text = "data 1" select xxx;


test   <--- now has the listviewitem with "data 1" as string value..
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To get an enumerator of `ListViewItem`, you have to cast the `Items` collection of ListView:

```
IEnumerable<ListViewItem> lv = listview1.items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
```

Then, you can use LINQ with it:

```
 var test = from xxx in lv 
            where xxx.text = "data 1" 
            select xxx;
```

Comment: I think you should use : `listview1.items.OfType<ListViewItem>();` to avoid a possible cast exception

Comment: @ Preet Sangha: I don't think it is needed, because, the item which is added to a ListView is always able to cast to `ListViewItem`

Answer (score 7):

```
ListViewItemCollections lv = listview1.items;

var test = from ListViewItem xxx in lv where xxx.text == "data 1" select xxx;
```

or

```
listview1.items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(i => i.text == "date 1");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit your search to just one column you can do so with

```
IEnumerable<ListViewItem> lv = listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();

var rows =  from x in lv
            where x.SubItems[columnIndex].Text == searchTerm
            select x;

if (rows.Count() > 0)
{
    ListViewItem row = rows.FirstOrDefault();

    //TODO with your row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListViewItemCollection` does only implement `IEnumerable` (instead of `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`), therefore the compiler cannot infer the type of `xxx` and the LINQ query doesn't work.

You need to cast the collection in order to work with it like

```
var test = from xxx in lv.Cast<ListViewItem>() where xxx.text="data 1" select xxx;
```